# Calling $http.get after $http.post angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to call my $http.get method after my $http.post method has FINISHED.
So I wrote a controller which is fired after clicking a button.

```
var app = angular.module("loginApp", []);

app.controller("ctrlLogin", function($scope, $http, $window, $timeout){
$scope.name = "";
$scope.key = "";

var message = {name: $scope.name, key: $scope.key};

$scope.setData = function(){
    message.name = $scope.name;
    message.key = $scope.key;

    $http.post('/getData', message)
      .then(function() {
          console.log("msg sent");

      }, function error() {
        console.log("msg failed");

      }).then(
            $http.get('/doLogon')
            .then(function() {
                console.log("logon");
            }, function error() {
                console.log("doLogon failed");

            }));
};
});
```

I still get the "logon" before "msg sent".
I need both functions to be executed when clicking the same button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why you have two `then` statements, please have a look at that:

```
$http.post('/getData', message)
  .then(function() {
      $http.get('/doLogon')
        .then(function() {
            console.log("logon");
        }, function() {
            console.log("doLogon failed");
        })
  }, function() {
    console.log("msg failed");
  })
```

Comment: Like this the http.get method dont get execuded properly. I get an error "nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError"

Comment: This looks like java exception, so your backend problem, nor angular

Comment: Okay, so at least the angular is correct now, thanks!